# Problem in installing PROJ in python environment

Tags: python, cartopy, proj

Cannot install `PROJ`

```
>>pip install git+https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ.git
```

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ.git
  Cloning https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ.git to c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-jwr6msmg
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-jwr6msmg\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-jwr6msmg\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-w2azftsy'
         cwd: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-jwr6msmg\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\python37\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-jwr6msmg\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried installing it manually using the source file, But it is also giving the following error

```
>>> pip install proj-7.1.1.tar.gz
```

```
Processing e:\wihg\15-09-2020\surfacewave tomography\iris_data\test\proj-7.1.1.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-3y5iufx3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-3y5iufx3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-2t2y4p78'
         cwd: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-3y5iufx3\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\python37\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-3y5iufx3\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How to solve this error? (Have to install it in Non-conda environment)

Comment: Could you show us what is in C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-jwr6msmg Did the data download? Did the directory not create?

Comment: Nope!! that directory is not created !!! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROJ is a C library, not a Python package, so you cannot use `pip` to install it.

If you just want to work with PROJ from Python, you can use PyPROJ and install it with `pip install pyproj`. On MacOS, Linux, and Windows this will give you pre-built wheels that already include PROJ.

If you're trying to install it for CartoPy (based on your tags) you'll need to install PROJ separately following [their install instructions](https://proj.org/install.html).